# Adding some alias with bash script and sourcing the .bashrc file from within the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, source

Hi I am trying to automate some post-installation tasks and to have them documented on my github account. That's why I am writing a script to install some additional packets and to add couple of new alias to the `.bashrc` file and I want to source the `.bashrc` file afterwards. This is the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script was inspired by the post of Remy Sharp: https://remysharp.com/2018/08/23/cli-improved

bashrc_loc="$HOME/.bashrc"

package_installation() {
        # Updating, upgrading and installing some additional packages
        sudo apt update
        sudo apt-get upgrade -y
        sudo apt-get install ncdu \
                tldr \
                ag \
                bat \
                prettyping \
                fzf \
                csvkit -y
        sudo apt-get autoremove -y
}

alias_add() {
        # Adding the alias in the ~/.bashrc file
        sed -i "\$aalias help='tldr'" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aalias du='ncdu --color dark -rr -x --exclude .git --exclude node_modules'" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aalias top='sudo htop'" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aalias preview=\"fzf --height 40% --preview 'if file -i {}|grep -q binary; then file -b {}; else bat --color \"always\" --line-range :40 {}; fi'\"" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aexport FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS=\"--bind='ctrl-o:execute(code {})+abort'\"" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aalias ping='prettyping --nolegend'" "$bashrc_loc"
        sed -i "\$aalias cat='bat'" "$bashrc_loc"
        source "$bashrc_loc"
}
```

So I was wondering if it is possible to add `source .bashrc` afterwards from within the script because it is trying to run the file and if I add this line to the bottom, shellcheck is reporting `^-- SC1090: Can't follow non-constant source. Use a directive to specify location.`

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem putting `source ~/.bashrc` at the end of the script. However that will only affect the current shell session you're working in. Any future logins will have the new modified `.bashrc`  loaded anyway

Comment: Just a pro tip: Never try to do in-place edits on important files (_especially_ not during development). Instead, write the result to a new file and back up the original before replacing it. Also, `sed` is more than capable of doing several operations on one file. There's no need to run `sed` on the same file seven times.

Comment: @Kusalananda that's a good tip, I will add a `cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_bkp` to my script.